# How modify /etc/network/interfaces without gedit?

Tags: interface, permissions, gedit

I'm doing a script and I would like to add the following line

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

to the file interfaces which is located on */etc/network/interfaces*,but although I have enabled the permissions to write in this file(I work in Ubuntu), I'm not able to do it... I'm trying to use the following command in my bash script

```
sudo echo "pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules" >> /etc/network/interfaces
```

Any suggestion of how  to do it without using gedit o vi?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell bash not to use redirection before it starts sudo:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules" >> /etc/network/interfaces'
```

this way the complete command will be executed with root access, not only the `echo "pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules"` part

Comment: I think it doesn't work properly since I was retrieved this message sudo: echo "pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules" >> /etc/network/interfaces: command not found

Comment: now it does work! thanks, I understand that I should pass the entire option as a command